# If I have a variable, assigned to the value of a function call, can that variable be updated if the function call's parameters are changed?

Tags: javascript, variables, function-call

If I have a function, like this:

```
function f(x,y){
 return x + y;
}
```

And if I have variables of parameters I want passed to f:

```
var parameter1;
var parameter2;
```

If I assign this function call to a variable:

```
var functionCallValue = f(parameter1,parameter2);
```

How can I ensure that functionCallValue changes depending on different values I assign to the variable parameter1 and parameter2?

Comment: ... you might have to explain yourself in a different way, or provide an example; I don't understand your question.

Comment: Different return values depend on the arithmetic operations of your function.

Answer (score 0):

`functionCallValue` is assigned the result (returnvalue) of your function `f`. (The function is called, the value calculated and the result handed over to your variable.) Thus `functionCallValue` does not automatically update, if you change the parameters (which would make no sense at all), you need to call the function again with the altered parameters.

For something like an auto-update you need a closure like this:

```
var asdf = (function(){

    var param1 = 1;
    var param2 = 2;
    var result = param1+param2;

    function compute(){
        result = param1 + param2;
    }

    return{
        param1:function(x){
           param1 = x;
           compute();
        },
        param2:function(x){
           param2 = x;
           compute();
        },
        result:function(){
           return result;            
        }
    }
})();
console.log(asdf.result()); // logs 3

asdf.param1(3);

console.log(asdf.result());​ // logs 5
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fTaV4/1/)**

Comment: The parameter I'm using is an array, and another function splices elements from that array. Do I have to call asdf.param1(array); each time an element is spliced from it?

Comment: each time you want the result, you have to update the params first of course.

Comment: @user1456713 If we helped you resolve your issue feel free to accept an answer to indicates to other StackOverflow users, that your problem has been solved. If you have some followup question, just ask it in the comments or probably better, open a new question.

Comment: Would you have any advise for this related problem: I am using the return value of functionX in nested loopY, which is why I wanted to assign its value to a variable first as my browser crashes because of functionX being called multiple times. But within loopY, the parameter of functionX is changed (array element removed), before being restored for the next iteration. Is there a way to optimize the code i.e avoid calling functionX constantly?

Comment: @user well, thats a bit difficult to judge and evaluate in the comments section. I recommend you to close this question by accepting one of the answers (if you are satisfied with it) and ask a new question for this followup-problem.

Comment: @user1456713 And, have you already made some progress with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you need is [a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

```
var servant = function(x, y) { return x + y; };

var param1  = 40;
var param2  = 2;
var master  = function() { return servant(param1, param2) };

var result = master();        // 42.  
param1 = 2;
param2 = 40;
var anotherResult = master(); // still 42, because that's really the answer!
```